# rdbuf in basic_ios and basic_fstream

Tags: c++, oop, std

I was checking the documentation for basic_ios which has the following methods:

[image]

but when I saw basic_fstream i found this:

[image]

AFAIK C++ cannot have two functions with the same name but different return type. Is it something related to how OOP works?

I tried with a simple demo like this and it works and to be honest I don't understand why.

[image]

So my question is:
**What is happening there?**

Comment: No pictures of code or otherwise plain text here please!

Comment: In addition to posting the code as text, you can post a link to the Godbolt (compiler explorer) page (get it under the "share" menu in Godbolt).

Answer (score 3):

Non-virtual methods in a derived class are unrelated to methods of the same name in a base class. This has a few potentially surprising effects, for example this code won't compile:

```
struct Foo
{
    void foo();
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    void foo(int);
};

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    bar.foo();
}
```

Though you might expect the base class `foo()` to be callable from `Bar` it isn't because `foo(int)` isn't an overload of the base class method, its a new method with the same name. If you want to have it as an overload you need to explicitly import it from the base class:

```
struct Bar : Foo
{
    using Foo::foo;
    void foo(int);
};
```

The same applies in the case of `rdbuf`, the method in `std::basic_fstream` is allowed to return a different type because its not the same function, its a new function with the same name.

This doesn't apply to virtual functions, this code won't compile as `foo` is now overriding the base class so must match:

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual void foo();
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    int foo();
};
```

Though note even with virtual functions you can introduce a new method with different arguments and again it'll hide the base class virtual method unless explicitly imported:

```
struct Foo
{
    virtual void foo();
};

struct Bar : Foo
{
    void foo(int);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have two functions with the same signature, if they are in different scopes. A derived class is like an inner scope compared to its base classes.

The new function will hide similar named things in the base class.